# Como acessar e manipular uma página Web da mesma forma que o usuário faria pelo navegador?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou planejando fazer um software que publica tópicos em um fórum. A tela inicial terá um menu com todas as categorias e subcategorias, ao escolher uma vou abrir em segundo plano um *link* (link para se criar um novo tópico), daí o usuário será redirecionado a outra tela na qual terá os campos de título e conteúdo do tópico de acordo com a categoria.

Queria saber como integro, por exemplo: Pegar o texto de um campo "Título" no meu programa e colocar no `input` com id `subject` da página html que está em segundo plano.

Por fim, no botão de enviar tenho uma função Javascript no `onClick`, como faço as ações de atribuição e textos nos inputs e depois chamar a função o `onClick`?

Se puderem me dar o que pesquisar, ou um exemplo a seguir eu ficaria grato, pois pesquisei e não achei nada parecido.

Considerando esse código HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
         <h1> Titulo </h1>
         <form>
             <input type="text" id="subject"/>
             <input onclick="envia();" type="submit" id="envia" value="Enviar"/>
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Como colocar um texto no `input` com ID `subject` da página, e ao clicar no botão o formulário chamar a função `envia()` da página?

Comment: Cara, não consegui entender muito bem o que tu queres fazer. Tem como editar a questão e tentar explicar melhor?

Comment: Vou editar e colocar mais detalhes

Comment: Use o [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: O post foi editado

Comment: Eu entendi o que você quer fazer porque já criei algo semelhante, mas sua pergunta está um pouco confusa. Não tenho experiência em C# mas em Java existe um *framework* chamado [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), por meio dele você pode preencher os campos de uma página html, pressionar botões, etc... procurei no SOen por algo semelhante e encontrei [essa pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2463735/4056678).

Comment: Ok, vou dar uma olhada, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se não for um problema a sua aplicação abrir um browser, você pode utilizar o Selenium.

Alterei um pouco o seu código web exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1> Titulo </h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="subject" />
        <!--
            Erro ao colocar o Id do botão com o mesmo nome da function do onclick, alterei o nome da function para enviar
            Tirei o type submit e troquei por button para que nao fizesse um submit no form
            <input onclick="envia();" type="submit" id="envia" value="Enviar" />
            
            -->
        <input onclick="enviar();" type="button" id="envia" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
    <script>
        function enviar() {
            var subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
            alert("Subject: " + subject);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Fiz um exemplo utilizando windows forms.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //utilize a url do site que você deseja preencher
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:7547/index.html");

        //note que mudei esta linha em relação ao ex. lá ele usa o attribute Name, aqui uso o Id
        IWebElement subject = driver.FindElement(By.Id("subject"));
        subject.SendKeys("Cheese");

        IWebElement button = driver.FindElement(By.Id("envia"));
        button.Click();
    }
```

Alguns exemplos no site do Selenium:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example

Caso queira fazer isso sem abrir o browser, procure sobre XVFB Selenium, não sei se existe solução para C#.

Utilize o Nuget para adicionar o Selenium em seu projeto:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso queira mais informações sobre esse tipo de funcionalidade procure por Web Scrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi exatamente o que você precisa.
Se você está fazendo um projeto windows forms que por trás acessa um site (fórum) você pode usar o [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
WebBrowser oWebBrowser = new WebBrowser(); // Instancia o Browser
oWebBrowser.Navigate("https://www.seuforum.com.br"); // Acessa a URL do fórum
oWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("subject").SetAttribute("value","SEU VALOR"); // muda o texto do input
oWebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { "envia()" }); // invoca a função envia() do html
```

Comment: O problema disso é que os meus elementos não contém ID e ele associa por id

Comment: se não é pelo ID, por qual atributo você vai encontrar o elemento?

Comment: Pode ser pelo Name ou Class, pois não são todos input que possuem IDs a outra resposta ali até parecia ter servido, testei mas deu um erro e não tive tempo de pesquisar

Comment: se for por Name você pode usar o GetElementsByName ao invés do GetElementById. Se for por Class você pode fazer usar o GetElementsByTagName e depois fazer um foreach e verificar quais dos elementos tem a classe que você quer, usando o GetAttribute("className")